# Override phtml of a module from another module

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml

I created a module and now I want to override a `.phtml` file from another module.
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overwrite a `.phtml` file from another module in a new module, you must first declare that the new module is dependent on the module you want to overwrite the `.phtml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourVendorname_YourModulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="SequenceVendorname_SequenceModulename"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

After that, you have to use the layout where the `.phtml` the file is declared or the **Block** in which it is declared.

#### From Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sequence_block_name">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">YourVendorname_YourModulename::folder/file.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sequence_block_name" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sequence_container">
            <block class="SequenceVendorname\SequenceModulename\Block\BlockName" name="your_block_name" template="YourVendorname_YourModulename::folder/file.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

#### From Block:

If the `.phtml` file is declared in a **Block**, then you must extend that **Block** in your module and declare the new path of the `.phtml` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `.phtml` template using custom module by adding **sequence** into `module.xml` and then overwritting your layout with template.

Here is example `module.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendor_ComponentB" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Vendor_ComponentA" />
    </sequence> 
  </module>
</config>
```

Follow this link for more detail instructions: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

Comment: I'm new to Magento. Could you explain this more detailled? Thanks so far :-)

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer :)

Comment: I hope it helps!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem to keep the community tidy.